# Can I configure IPFire (ARM) to use SSH by default?

Tags: linux

I want to play with IPFire on my Pi, but I don't have a keyboard nor mouse to control it with. Is there a way to enable SSH by editing the image directly?

Comment: It has a web interface, so why not use that from another box? If you really want to, grab the [source](http://www.ipfire.org/development), make the symlinks, and rebuild the image

Comment: Getting the image to work will require more than that, if it can be done at all (IPFire's ARM image targets ARMv5, whereas the pi is ARMv6 and the pi 2 ARMv7; in theory they are backward compatible but...): You can't use a vanilla kernel on the pi, so you will have to replace that, and the modules.

Answer (score 0):

IPFire has a web interface that you should be able to access and enable SSH on. Editing the image will require a lot more work than you might be thinking. It isn't something that you can just quickly edit.

To access the web interface use the URL (example) `https://192.168.1.1:444/`, which should match the one you used for the GREEN interface. Enter the username as “admin” and password that you set up during the installation.

You can read more [here](http://wiki.ipfire.org/en/configuration/system/ssh).

Comment: Why do you think the image is so difficult to modify? In my experience the `PAKfire` package manager's dir is just a flat folder list - one per package. That was a couple of years ago, though. As I recall, `PAKfire` seemed to behave very like `pacman`, actually.